# Spring-boot with maven - exclude on test scope dependency

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-3

This is my whole pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shadov.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run` it doesn't work - `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`. I excluded `spring-jcl` that contains this missing class - so this is expected.

Now I remove `spring-jcl` exclude on `spring-boot-starter-test` and it starts to work. I'm super confused - how does the exclude from `test` scope dependency has anything to do with running application? Is this some weird maven behavior, or spring-boot maven plugin looks at `test` scoped dependencies for some reason (if that's even possible)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's may because of `requiresDependencyResolution=ResolutionScope.TEST` in RunMojo.java.

[RunMojo.java#L44-L45](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/RunMojo.java#L44-L45)